# Jira oauth2 App client_id not registered for redirect_uri

Tags: jira, redirect-uri, redirect-uri-mismatch

I have an JIra app configured for  oAuth2 where I use only use url as an redurect_uri and on the request side, I pass the full url as a redirect_url.

for ex. on Jira developer configuration, my redirect_uri is "https://example.com" and on client side I pass "https://example.com/xyz" as `xyz` is dynamic rooms. User should be redirected to the room from which he requested.

This scenario was working well for me but suddenly stopped working and now Jira app only allows "https://example.com" as a qualified url and returning "client_id not registered for redirect_uri" for "https://example.com/xyz" .

Can anyone help me quickly

I was passing "https://example.com" as a redirect_uri on Atlassian configuration side and using full url while requesting token which was working okay and it suddenly stopped working now. Its only work for "https://example.com/" url now and returns client_id not registered for "https://example.com/xyz"

Answer (score 0):

I had the essentially the same question this last week.

Got an answer [on the community forum](https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/oauth2-redirect-uri-not-registered-for-client-but-nothing-changed/69113/5) that confirms that they are looking at the entire URL (scheme://domain/path) and not just scheme://domain leaving path to be specified in the auth calls.

Not sure when that changed as it had been working for me before. Also not sure why token refreshes continued to function - only *new* connections were rejected...

As a side note, I was concerned that the change in registered callback URL would somehow invalidate all the accepted scope grants--but unfounded. Changed the URL and everything worked just fine.